Python script which delete every N-th file in folder
This question has been answered few times, but all answers (all scripts) are not working, they delete files randomly. I tried all.
For example this script doesn't work (here it should delete every 2nd file):
import os
dir_to_clean = 'folderpath'
l = os.listdir(dir_to_clean)
for n in l[::2]:
    target = dir_to_clean + '/' + n
    if os.path.isfile(target):
        os.unlink(target)

It deletes files randomly like all other scripts here. Is there a way to fix it or just another way to do that task using Python?

What distinguishes "randomly" from "every N-th"? Do you expect the values to be in some kind of sort order?

...if you want them to be in a sort order, don't count on the filesystem to enforce that (some do, some don't, some it depends on configuration options or flags used when that filesystem was created) -- instead, use sorted(os.listdir(dir_to_clean)).

The filenames are not stored in the directory in sorted order, so picking every other file from the directory will probably look random. You should sort the list yourself in your code before using it (e.g. l = sorted(os.listdir(dir_to_clean))

Well if i need to delete every 2nd file out of 1 2 3 4 5 6 for example it should result in 1 3 5. It gives random like 1 2 5 6 etc

Tried your lines but it still gives some files randomly. But result is better. Still some files are not 2nd but random

Case was in files names. Now it works. Thanks.
